# Dibiphp single quotes issue

Tags: php

I am using [dibiphp](http://dibiphp.com/) for sql queries , this requires an array to be passed to update value in database like

```
$args=array('field1'=>$value,'fiel2'=>$value2);
```

The problem is if the value contain single quotes `'` the text after it is truncated (not saved to database)

eg `here's an example` is saved as `here`, I tried posting in form and dint got any reply to it, If somebody has used dibiphp , he can easily guide me in what I am doing wrong, below is class function, I tried `print_r` for `$args` value reaches properly till the query is executed

```
public function updateVideo($id, array $args)
{
    return dibi::query('UPDATE [videos] SET', $args, 'WHERE id = %i', $id);
}
```

Comment: Did you try escaping the `'`? And what if you use `"`?

Comment: You might want to use [this function](http://api.dibiphp.com/2.1/source-drivers.DibiMySqliDriver.php.html#284-315) before assigning your values to the array.

Comment: Yes I tried escaping but escaping works till the query is not fired

Comment: any answer to my problem

Comment: @AkshatSinghal if  i use " instead of ' , it wont make sense to readers don't will be dont"t so i havent tried this